# Which bluetooth headphones work best?

Tags: 10.04, bluetooth, headphones

While I can see there is a lot of info available on setting up the headphones, but before I buy one I would like to know from the community if anyone tried setting up a bluetooth headphone on Ubuntu Lucid and which brands work well with Ubuntu.

- Not looking for anything expensive
- Should be easy to configure repeatably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any should be fine now.

There are however few important things to remember:

1. Blueman (`sudo aptitude install blueman`) is better than default bluetooth applet
2. Cheap bluetooth adapters usually do not work well.
3. If you want to listen to music, you should get stereo headset that support A2DP profile.
4. Switch from stereo to headset mode is not automatic but it is easily done with 
   pavucontrol (`sudo aptitude install pavucontrol`, last tab)

Other than that it all works out of the box.